# Twisted callRemote

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, twisted

I have to make remote calls that can take quite a long time (over 60 seconds). Our entire code relies on processing the return value from the callRemote, so that's pretty bad since we're blocking on IO the whole time despite using twqisted + 50 worker threads running.

We currently use something like

```
result = threads.blockingCallFromThread(reactor, callRemote, "method", args)
```

and get the result/go on, but as its name says it's blocking the event loop so we cannot wait for several results at the same time.

THere's no way I can refactor the whole code to make it asynchronous so I think the only way is to defer the long IO tasks to threads.

I'm trying to make the remote calls in threads, but I can't find a way to get the result from the blocking calls back. The remoteCalls are made, the result is somewhere but I just can't get a hook on it.

What I'm trying to do currently looks like

```
reactor.callInThread(callRemote, name, *args, **kw)
```

which returns a empty Deferred (why ?).

I'm trying to put the result in some sort of queue but it just won't work. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, `blockingCallFromThread` executes code in `reactor`'s thread. That's why it doesn't work as you need.

If I understand you properly, you need to move some operation out off `reactor`s thread and get the result into `reactor`s thread.

I use approach with `deferToThread` for the same case. 
Example with deferreds:

```
import time
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads

def doLongCalculation():
    time.sleep(1)
    return 3

def printResult(x):
    print x

# run method in thread and get result as defer.Deferred
d = threads.deferToThread(doLongCalculation)
d.addCallback(printResult)
reactor.run()
```

Also, you might be interested in `threads.deferToThreadPool`.

[Documentation about threading in Twisted.](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.0.0/core/howto/threading.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but actually I've already tried that and a couple other things, and I get a Deferred back (i.e. it prints '<Deferred at 0x...>), not the result I get when I do a blockingCallFromThread. Any idea ? I guess it has something to do with nested deferreds, but I can't find a way to force the inner deferreds to fire.

Comment: Also I've tried reactor.callInThread which doesn't work either, I wonder what's the difference between reactor.callInThread and threads.deferToThread ?

Comment: Regarding nested deferreds, my advice is to try to refactor your code with `@defer.inlineCallback` if possible. I've just looked into the source of `blockingCallFromThread` http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-16.0.0/twisted/internet/threads.py#L93. The code uses `Queue.Queue` for storing results from callback and errback. My 2nd advice: try to mimic `blockingCallFromThread` and approach with `Queue`, but use `callInThread` for moving computation to a separate thread.

Comment: Note, the main difference between `reactor.callInThread` and `threads.deferToThread` is that the last one returns result as deferred out of the box. BTW, `threads.deferToThread` uses `reactor.callFromThread`.

Comment: Ok, I somehow got it. There was indeed a nested callback ; if I go for `res = threads.deferToThread(callRemote, method, *args, **kw)`, it returns res as a deferred. After some time (up to 60 seconds) the deferred fires and I can get its result in res.result.result. I don't know how to wait for the result in a non blocking way. I launched some kind of "poll" procedure in a separate thread, which checks every **x** seconds if the deferred has fired but for some reason the app blocks in the waiting procedure.

Comment: You can add a callback to the deferred `res = threads.deferToThread(callRemote, method, *args, **kw)`. In that case, you won't need "polling".